# Importing large .xlsx file very slow

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I'm new to c# and WPF and trying to import a large .xlsx file into a datagrid, i can have around 200+ columns & 100,000+ rows. With my current method it is taking over an hour (i didn't let it finish). An example of my format in csv terms would be;

```
"Time","Dist","V_Front","V_Rear","RPM"
"s","m","km/h","km/h","rpm"
"0.000","0","30.3","30.0","11995"
"0.005","0","30.3","30.0","11965"
"0.010","0","30.3","31.0","11962"
```

I'm using Interop at the moment but i'm wondering whether there is another approach which would drastically cut down load time. I hope to plot this data using SciCharts (they have a student licence), with check boxes for channel selection but that's another matter.

.CS

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
        openfile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
        openfile.Filter = "(.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

        var browsefile = openfile.ShowDialog();

        if (browsefile == true)
        {
            txtFilePath.Text = openfile.FileName;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text.ToString(), 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1); ;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

            string strCellData = "";
            double douCellData;
            int rowCnt = 0;
            int colCnt = 0;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
            {
                string strColumn = "";
                strColumn = (string)(excelRange.Cells[1, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                dt.Columns.Add(strColumn, typeof(string));
            }

            for (rowCnt = 2; rowCnt <= excelRange.Rows.Count; rowCnt++)
            {
                string strData = "";
                for (colCnt = 1; colCnt <= excelRange.Columns.Count; colCnt++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        strCellData = (string)(excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                        strData += strCellData + "|";
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        douCellData = (excelRange.Cells[rowCnt, colCnt] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).Value2;
                        strData += douCellData.ToString() + "|";
                    }
                }
                strData = strData.Remove(strData.Length - 1, 1);
                dt.Rows.Add(strData.Split('|'));
            }

            dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            excelBook.Close(true, null, null);
            excelApp.Quit();


        }
    }
```

Any help i really appreciated.

Comment: Rather than inserting each row individually, it would probably be faster to put it all into a `List` of a custom object that can be data bound.

Comment: You could want to use `StringBuilder`s, because you do a lot of operations on strings.

Comment: Have you tried using OLEDB to fill the DataTable?

Comment: DiskJunky do you mean i should load column into a separate list or one large list?

Equalsk - No, i will look into it now. Thanks

Comment: Equalsk - I have got OLEDB in the program now however getting: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is too many individual reads which causes a lot of reflection usage and marshalling between Excel and your application. If you're not concerned about memory usage, you can just read the whole `Range` into memory and work from memory instead of individually reading cells. The below code runs in 3880 ms on a test file with 5 columns and 103938 rows:

```
OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
openfile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
openfile.Filter = "(.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

var browsefile = openfile.ShowDialog();

if (browsefile == true)
{
    txtFilePath.Text = openfile.FileName;

    var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtFilePath.Text, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
    var excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) excelBook.Worksheets.Item[1];

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    object[,] value = excelRange.Value;

    int columnsCount = value.GetLength(1);
    for (var colCnt = 1; colCnt <= columnsCount; colCnt++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add((string)value[1, colCnt], typeof(string));
    }

    int rowsCount = value.GetLength(0);
    for (var rowCnt = 2; rowCnt <= rowsCount; rowCnt++)
    {
        var dataRow = dt.NewRow();
        for (var colCnt = 1; colCnt <= columnsCount; colCnt++)
        {
            dataRow[colCnt - 1] = value[rowCnt, colCnt];
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }

    dtGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

    excelBook.Close(true);
    excelApp.Quit();
}
```

If you don't want to read the whole `Range` in, then you should do that in sensible batches.

Another optimization is to run this on a background thread, so it won't block the UI while it's loading.

**Edit**

For running this on a background thread you could modify the button click handler to be an async method and put the parsing logic into another method which runs the actual parsing on a threadpool thread with `Task.Run`:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
    openfile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
    openfile.Filter = "(.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

    var browsefile = openfile.ShowDialog();

    if (browsefile == true)
    {
        txtFilePath.Text = openfile.FileName;

        DataTable dataTable = await ParseExcel(txtFilePath.Text).ConfigureAwait(true);

        dtGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
    }
}

private Task<DataTable> ParseExcel(string filePath)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        var excelBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath, 0, true, 5, "", "", true,
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        var excelSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) excelBook.Worksheets.Item[1];

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range excelRange = excelSheet.UsedRange;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        object[,] value = excelRange.Value;

        int columnsCount = value.GetLength(1);
        for (var colCnt = 1; colCnt <= columnsCount; colCnt++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add((string) value[1, colCnt], typeof(string));
        }

        int rowsCount = value.GetLength(0);
        for (var rowCnt = 2; rowCnt <= rowsCount; rowCnt++)
        {
            var dataRow = dt.NewRow();
            for (var colCnt = 1; colCnt <= columnsCount; colCnt++)
            {
                dataRow[colCnt - 1] = value[rowCnt, colCnt];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        excelBook.Close(true);
        excelApp.Quit();

        return dt;
    });
}
```

The handler just invokes the parsing function, the parsing function runs on a background thread and when it finishes the handler can continue by assigning the resulting `DataTable` to the `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes good sense. Can you explain a bit more about running this on a background thread? Cheers